# Windows Phone 8 HTML5 - local vs remote HTML performance

Tags: performance, html, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have an HTML5 game set up using the 'Windows Phone HTML5 App' template. This essentially just loads the HTML Game in a WebBrowser control.

When loading index.html locally with a relative URI, performance is dismal with the profiler showing about 10fps:

When loading exactly the same HTML, only from my remote server, I'm getting a good 45fps.

Does anyone have any idea what this disparity is and how to fix it?

**Edit -> When loading all images remotely the performance issues are gone. The problem lies in loading images locally, rather than remotely. Bewildering.**

**Edit 2 -> Base64 encoding the images as data URIs also has the same massive performance gains. Unfortunately that isn't workable for us, but shows something is seriously wrong with loading images locally**

Comment: Just curious: when you load the html from server, so you load it in the embedded WebBrowser control or in IE? On iOS the WebView component performs much worse than the mobile Safari, because the WebView uses an older version of the rendering engine. If you tried the online content only in IE, it could be something like this.

Comment: Yep, it's being loaded in the WebBrowser control. I'm literally just changing the URI from local to remote, and seeing vastly improved performance.

Comment: That's nuts! I don't have a WP8 device to try this on, but sure sounds like an interesting issue. Hope you find a solution!

Comment: Just to get some hard data on this problem, maybe you could run the Sunspider (or similar) browser speed test both from the web and locally? You can use the Save as... feature in desktop Chrome or Firefox to save the test driver page and all related scripts. (http://www.webkit.org/perf/sunspider/sunspider.html)

Comment: Random guess - any chance that local page ends up with IE7/IE8 mode (different zones - could be different browsers). Check if you have `<!DOCTYPE html>` in both HTML files...

Comment: Yep, the HTML is exactly the same with correct doctype and X-UA-Compatible meta tag is using Edge.

I downloaded the SunSpider rep here: https://github.com/cheald/SunSpider-deadcode. I could't get it running locally in the WebBrowser control though. It never displays the results page.

Comment: After further inspection when I load all my images remotely rather than locally then the framerate is excellent again. This just gets stranger. Any ideas why loading images locally would cause such massive slowdown?

Comment: post a simple repro, i'll send it to the team....

Comment: @HenryHoffman, re: images. Maybe the browser returns the remote image requests from cache, but doesn't cache locally stored files. The lag you see could be caused by reading the images from disk every time you load one.

Comment: @fencliff That would make sense if initial loading was slow, but the canvas framerate is consistently slow, even long after loading the images.

Comment: @HenryHoffman, yeah, I know I'm clutching at straws here, but what I meant was that when you add and remove images to DOM/Canvas, maybe remotely loaded images are loaded from in-memory cache, but local images reread from disk. This could be some memory optimization strategy. But IDK. Do you recycle your images or recreate them every time you need them?

Comment: My personal guess: Some security rule switches off JavaScript compilation. More specifically: Maybe you load some parts locally and some remotely and thus create something like a XSS issue. This might lead to IE checking each request for some security stuff and/or might switch off JS compilation. Just a guess though...

Answer (score 1):

Have you found the cause of the problem?

First, in order to make sure you do not have any xss issue can you setup Fiddler for example and monitor the traffic on the phone?

Second, crazy idea: would it work to make a simple http server in your own app? you can then set the webbrowser load your game from it and see how that works compared to loading from local

Comment: Still no solution at present. Embedding an http server sounds interesting as it would solve some other issues I've run in to. Is there any documentation on doing such a thing?

Comment: it's relatively easy. just create and start listening a Socket on IPAddress.Any, port 80. Here's a tutorial which I think will work on WP too. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te.aspx Afterwards you need to implement responding with files. Are you targetting WP7 or just WP8?

Comment: I think I might be able to give you a sample in few days if you can wait. It responds with a simple HTML content, but in your case you will have to implement responding with files

Comment: That sounds great, I can definitely wait :)

Comment: It is listening to localhost port 80 connections and responds with a HTML content. the way to test it is to put a WebBrowser control in the test app since you will need that anyway. However, my solution is far from complete as I do not handle properly different things like handle the case when incoming or sending data is larger than the buffer, handle the connection using ThreadPool, etc. I suggest you ready the documentation about sockets and / or use this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/83102/C-SocketAsyncEventArgs-High-Performance-Socket-Cod

Comment: The article from codeproject is very good and I think you can use most of it on Windows Phone. Please post an update with what you find regarding your issue.